# C# Enum for datatypes

Tags: c#, enums

Is there any enum in c# which holds c#  datatypes. So that I can define a property in a class which accepts datatype (int,string) from the user.

Comment: I'm a bit scared at the thought of why you'd want this, but no I don't think there is...

Comment: do you need an union equivalent in c#?

Answer (score 8):

There is the [TypeCode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode(v=vs.110).aspx) in System. Looks like it covers all of the base types.

You can get the TypeCode for any object using Type.GetTypeCode():

```
TypeCode typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(anObject.GetType());
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you simply want to associate an enum value with a string? You might want to use the `Description` attribute.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("My first value.")]
    FirstValue,
    [Description("My second value.")]
    SecondValue,
    [Description("My third value.")]
    ThirdValue
}

private string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    if (attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        return attributes[0].Description;
    }
    else
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Another possibility for defining a mapping would be to use a `Dictionary<int, string>`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a boolean property of Type-type "IsPrimitive" hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit sounds like you need [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx) but I still question why a property would acceptably be an int or a string. Those are really very different things which can only lead to upcasting.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that in the BCL.

Why do you need it?

Comment: There is  DataType enum in the namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations but it has values like PhoneNumber,EmailAddress etc.

Comment: @Daniel Joseph - those are not just _primitive_ types, as you have asked about. And this Enum is there to support ASP.NET MVC and Dynamic Data controls (so they can be annotated for use on _other_ platforms as well).

Comment: There is the `System.TypeCode` enum for primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that? The property is already a "filter" to what kind of data it can accept.

Have a look at :

[Overloading properties in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608892/overloading-properties-in-c)